# How can I get data from 1 Table and 'POST' it to Another Table (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have question. I have 2 different tables, 1st is user and the 2nd is consultation. I want when user make the consultation, the user_id from the 1st table is posted to the 2nd 'user_id' column too.

my controller is like this and I don't know how to do

```
public function add_detail_consultation()
    {
        $this->load->helper('date');
        $data_consultation['data_consultation'] = $this->db->get('consultation')->row();
        $date = date('Y-m-d');
        $data = array(
            'date' => $date,
            'user_id' => //I don't know what to do in this section :(
        );
        $this->db->insert('consultation', $data);
}
```

Can you help me? it will help me a lot! thanks

Comment: Is this a method in a controller? Does this method run after user is logged in?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function add_detail_consultation()
    {
        $this->load->helper('date');
        $data_consultation = $this->db->get('consultation')->row();
        $date = date('Y-m-d');
        $data = array(
            'date' => $date,
            'user_id' => $data_consultation['user_id']
        );
        $this->db->insert('consultation', $data);
     }
```